# Chafez Chayim checked copies of (which) books?

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, agada-stories-legends, inspection, chofetz-chaim

I've heard that [the *Chafetz Chayim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisrael_Meir_Kagan) inspected each page of each printed copy of [the *Mishna B'rura*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah_Berurah) to be sure that it was printed correctly (with no large ink splotches or the like).

- Is there a reliable source for this fact?
- Which printings of the *Mishna B'rura* — and other books, if any — did he do this to?

Comment: In the Kollel Yad Shaul in Johannesburg there was an old copy (from the turn of the 19th century, IIRC) of the Mishna Berura (Vol. 1 or 3) with מוגה written in the inside cover.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, turn of the **19th** century?

Comment: As in "when the 19th century was turning into the 20th".

Comment: I actually inherited a set of the Mishnah Brurah from my great-grandfather which has the מוגה written in it. There are date stamps Warsaw 1892, 1893, 1896, and 1898.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/feinhandler/archives/chayeisa.htm

> The Chofetz Chaim sighed deeply and said, "I too am a person who makes
>   mistakes. You know that I sell my books. Sometimes the binder
>   misplaces a page, or a page might be missing or have unclear print.
>   Even though I am careful to check every book before it is sold, there
>   still could be mistakes. The people who buy my books are embarrassed
>   to tell me when there is a defect, but in their hearts they really
>   care, and that is why I was also punished."

[This link](http://www.atid.org/upload/cc.JPG) - [from here](http://lamed.blogspot.com/2006/09/chofetz-chaim-autograph.html) shows a photograph of a Sefer the Chofetz chaim sold with the word "Mugah" handwritten by the Chofetz Chaim.

Answer (score 0):

In the Kollel Yad Shaul in Johannesburg, they had a volume of the Mishna Berura with the word מוגה in the front cover.

It was an early copy - very early 1900's IIRC.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, which was about the author's checking them personally.